# Docker Windows 11 Cannot Bind to Network

Tags: docker-desktop, windows-11

Running Docker Desktop (lates v as of 9/1/23), installed and pulled-run images for CodeProject AI server as well as Portainer.  Able to start the containers, but will not bind to any network for me to access as localhost on win machine or to nroader network.

I have installed Docker Desktopfor windows, I need to run an AI server app (CodeProjectAI) for image recognition. I am unable to bind the containers to my network at all.  Tried using WSL2 and HyperV, tried installing Portainer, same issue. Much appreciate anyone who can point to the correct instructions or help me trouble shoot. Thanks.Installed Docker Desktop Windows 11, both WSL2 and HyperV.  Made sure windows apps for WSl etc. all turned on.  Trying to run CodeprojectAI to analyze images as a server for use by Blue Iris NVR.